# Play framework upload file not working

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I wanted to upload a CSV file and from there get the details in order to fill up a MySQL database. I am using Play! framework 2 with Java but i am having difficulties to implement this solution.

This is my Java code

```
       public static Result uploadfile() {
         File fl = request().body().asRaw().asFile();

          if (fl != null) {


            return ok("File uploaded");
          } else {
            flash("error", "Missing file");
            return redirect(routes.Application.index());    
          }
```

This is my Upload.Scala.html code

```
   @(uploadForm: Form[Application.upl])

   @import helper._

   @main("Upload file") {
      @form(action = routes.Application.uploadfile) {

         <input type="file" name="flname">

         <p>
            <input type="submit" value="upload">
         </p>

      }
   }
```

And finally my routes file

```
POST     /uploadfile                controllers.Application.uploadfile()
```

Once I hit upload an execution exception occurs saying that the `request().body().asRaw().asFile()` is actually `null`!

> [NullPointerException: null]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

===================================================================================
Ok so my current code is as follows
On application.java

```
  public static Result uploadfile() {
  play.mvc.Http.MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    FilePart flpart = body.getFile("fl") ;
    if (flpart != null) {

       File file = flpart.getFile();
       ImportCSV impCSV = new ImportCSV();
       try{
           if (file.exists()) 
           {
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(file));
               System.out.println(file.getName() + " - " + file.getAbsolutePath());
               impCSV.importCSV(br);
           }
           else
           {
               System.out.println("File not found!");
               return redirect(routes.Application.upload()); 
           }
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           System.err.println("Buffering file " + file.getName() +": " + e.getMessage());

       }
       return ok("File uploaded");
    } else {
       flash("error", "Missing file");
     return redirect(routes.Application.index());    
    }
}
```

And on the ImportCSV.java (which extends model)

```
public static void importCSV( BufferedReader br) 
{

    parseFile(br);


    if(vals!=null)
    {
        Student student = new Student();
        List<Student> newStudents;
        newStudents = GetStudentDetails(vals);
        try{
            student.insertStudentList(newStudents);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("student inserting Error: " + e.getMessage());

        }

    }
}

 static void parseFile( BufferedReader br) {
    try {

          String line = "";
          StringTokenizer token = null;
          int lineNum = 0, tokenNum = 0;

          List<values> CSVvalues = new LinkedList<values>();
          values LnValues = new values();
          while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                lineNum++;

                // break comma separated file line by line
                token = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
                LnValues = new values();
                while(token.hasMoreTokens()) {
                      tokenNum++;
                      switch(tokenNum)
                      {
                        //Student ID
                          case 0:
                          {
                              LnValues.setStudID(Long.getLong(token.nextToken()));
                          }
                          //Student Name
                          case 1:
                          {
                              LnValues.setStudName(token.nextToken());
                          }
                          //Student DoB
                          case 2:
                          {
                              LnValues.setStudDoB(Date.valueOf(token.nextToken()));
                          }
                          //Class
                          case 3:
                          {
                              LnValues.setCl(token.nextToken());
                          }
                          //Year
                          case 4:
                          {
                              LnValues.setYear(Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken()));
                          }
                          //Quarter
                          case 5:
                          {
                              LnValues.setQuarter(token.nextToken());
                          }
                          //Maths Grade
                          case 6:
                          {
                              LnValues.setGradeM( Float.parseFloat(token.nextToken()));
                          }
                          //Computer Science Grade
                          case 7:
                          {
                              LnValues.setGradeCS(Float.parseFloat(token.nextToken()));
                          }
                          //Literature grade
                          case 8:
                          {
                              LnValues.setGradeL( Float.parseFloat(token.nextToken()));
                          }                           

                      }


                }
                CSVvalues.add(LnValues);
                tokenNum = 0;
          }

          vals = CSVvalues;
    } catch(Exception e) {
          System.err.println("Parsing file  Error: " + e.getMessage());

    }
```

Once i pass the Buffered reader the data are null. At the beginning i tried to send the file (File fl) to the parameters but i also got null error. I tried @Util annotation shown in some cases but the compiler complains for not recognizing it! 
I am open to suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

There are instructions on how to do this here:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaFileUpload

`request().body().asRaw().asFile();` only works if you are using ajax to upload the file, if instead you are using the normal `POST` request, you should try the solution proposed in the documentation by using

```
public static Result upload() {
    MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    FilePart picture = body.getFile("picture");
    if (picture != null) {
       String fileName = picture.getFilename();
       String contentType = picture.getContentType(); 
       File file = picture.getFile();
       return ok("File uploaded");
    } else {
       flash("error", "Missing file");
       return redirect(routes.Application.index());    
    }
}
```

Also notice that you have to use the correct form format, here:

`@form(action = routes.Application.upload, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data")`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did change the code but once i pass the file to another function for parsing the function calls an exception for the file being null! I even tried to put the file into a bufferedreader and send it but still... nada! Using @Util prior the function create an error during the compilation for not finding u !!!!!

Comment: If you mean the file transition from the form to the Result function, it seems to do work. But otherwise the file is not sent to the secondary function in any way. Have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, can you add some example code?